# sendNotification continues to send emails if any cell in row with value trigger is updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using sendNotification to trigger an email when column 'G' has a value of 'All Components to DC'. But, the issue I am having is that when the column already has the data 'All Components at DC' and another column in the same row is updated (with any value), the script is checking column 'G' again and seeing the 'All Components at DC' and re-sending the same email.

How would the script need to be re-written so that the notification is only sent when column 'G' is updated and ignores the other cells in the same row?

```
function sendNotification(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getDisplayValue().toString();

  if(sheet.getRange('G'+row).getValue()=='All Components at DC')
  {
    var recipients = "xxx@xxx.com";
    var subject = "Delivered Items"
    var message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + '\n TITLE: ' + sheet.getRange('F'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + '\n LANGUAGE: ' + sheet.getRange('E'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
    var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + '\n ROW: ' + row + '\n DATE: ' + message + '\n COMMENT: ' + cellvalue;
    var valColB=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this answer?

- `sendNotification()` is installed as the installable trigger of OnEdit.
- You want to run `sendNotification()` only when a cell of column "G" is updated.

If my understanding of your situation is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
if(sheet.getRange('G'+row).getValue()=='All Components at DC')
```

#### To:

```
if(cell[0] == 'G' && sheet.getRange('G'+row).getValue()=='All Components at DC')
```

In this modification, by the script in `if` is run only when the column "G" was edited by adding `cell[0] == 'G'`.

And as an another modification, you can also use the event object of OnEdit. The following sample script uses the event object. When the event object is used, the process cost can be reduced.

#### Sample script using event object:

```
function sendNotification(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var values = range.offset(0, -6, 1, 6).getValues()[0];
  var activeCell = range.getValue();
  if (range.getA1Notation()[0] == 'G' && activeCell == 'All Components at DC') {
    var recipients = "xxx@xxx.com";
    var subject = "Delivered Items";
    var message = values[0] + '\n TITLE: ' + values[5] + '\n LANGUAGE: ' + values[4];
    var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + '\n ROW: ' + range.getRow() + '\n DATE: ' + message + '\n COMMENT: ' + activeCell;
    var valColB=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Benchmark: Event Objects for Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit:

#### About issue of this situation:

The event object has the old value of the edited cell. But in your case, the cell used as a trigger is not the edited cell. For example, under the condition that the columns "I" to "L" have the value of `Delivered to DC`, when `Delivered to DC` is put to the column "M" and the value of column "G" changes from `In Progress` to `All Components at DC`, the event object that the column "M" is edited is returned.  So the old and new values are not the value of column "G". And also when the value of column "G" is retrieved by the trigger, the value is the changed value. By those, in this situation, when the event object and trigger is used, the value of column "G" after changed is retrieved.

#### Workaround:

In order to avoid above issue, how about this workaround? In this workaround, I would like to propose to save the values of column "G" before editing. For this, I use a column. Although there are several methods, I thought that this workaround is simler. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. At first, save the current value of column "G" to a column using a function. This is a initialize of this flow.

   - In this sample, the column "N" is used as the column for saving the values before editing.
2. When the installable trigger is launched, it retrieves the past value from the column "N" and compares it with the new value. When the new value is changed to `All Components at DC`, it runs the script in `if` and send an email.
3. Update the values of column "N" to the current ones.

When the above flow is reflected to your script, please modify as follows. Also the script using the event object can be modified like the following script.

#### Modified script:

```
// Added
function saveCurrentValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker");
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 7, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(2, 14, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}

function sendNotification(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getDisplayValue().toString();
  var beforeEdit = sheet.getRange(1, 14, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); // Added
  if(sheet.getName()=='Tracker' && sheet.getRange('G'+row).getValue()=='All Components at DC' && beforeEdit[row - 1][0] != 'All Components at DC') // Modified
  {
    var recipients = "xxx@xxx.com";
    var subject = "New Components Delivered to DC"
    var message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + '\n TITLE: ' + sheet.getRange('F'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + '\n LANGUAGE: ' + sheet.getRange('E'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
    var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + '\n ROW: ' + row + '\n TVD DATE: ' + message + '\n COMMENT: ' + cellvalue;
    var valColB=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
  saveCurrentValues(); // Added
}
```

#### Note:

- `saveCurrentValues()` is used for saving the current values of column "G". So after you copied and pasted above scripts, at first, please run `saveCurrentValues()`. By this, the current values are saved to the column "N".

  - The column "N" was used as a sample. So please modify to your environment. You can also hide the column.
- In this workaround, when the value of column "G" is changed from `All Components at DC` to others, and it is not changed, the script in `if` is NOT run. So email is not sent.

Comment: Thanks for the response... the addition of cell[0] == 'G' seems to break the script.. no emails are received. Also, I tried to use the new event object script and that did not work either. Not sure if I had to modify something to get it working...

Comment: I think right now  ` var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();` refers to the activeCell that I manually update... so `cell[0] == 'G' ` would never happen, because 'G' has a custom formula that updates to the status of 'All Components at DC'... is that why that method you provided didn't work?

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. At first, if you installed ``sendNotification(e)`` as the installable trigger of OnEdit, please remove it and reinstall it, and try again. And then, in your situation, when you put ``All Components at DC`` to the column "G", the script in ``if`` isn't run by the installable trigger. Is my understanding is correct? Can you provide the situation you are using?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/177n7wITo6Gi-MgyR1qbOrzULM-fFrP3pcV6L8k9v1d4/edit?usp=sharing --- here is a sample spreadsheet where you can see how my formula in column 'G' works.

Comment: @Arm From your shared spreadsheet, it was found that there are important points which are not shown in your question. In order to understand correctly your situation, can I ask you about it? In your sample spreadsheet and script, under the column "H" has no ``DC Complete``, when the column from "I" to "M" are modified, the script in ``if`` is run. You want to avoid this? or under the condition, when the column from "A" to "F" are modified, the script in ``if`` is run. You want to avoid this?

Comment: Column H is not important. I only want the status in Column 'G' = All Components at DC to trigger the email. If Column "A" to "F" are modified AND Column 'G' = All Components at DC, then DO NOTHING. If Column "I" to "M" are modified and Column 'G' = All Components at DC, then DO NOTHING.  Only trigger email when oldValue of Column 'G' != 'All Components at DC' and newValue = 'All Components at DC'.... I hope this makes more sense?

Comment: @Arm Thank you for replying. For example, when the columns "I" to "L" have ``Delivered to DC``, when ``Delivered to DC`` is put to the column "M", the column "G" is changed from ``In Progress`` to ``All Components at DC``. At that time, you want to send an email. Namely, you are required to know the value of column "G" just before it is edited. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but it is not necessarily required to know the value of 'G'. I just need the email to send when G = All Components at DC. The current issue I have with my script is that If G2 = 'All Components at DC' and you update cell C2, D2, E2.... etc... basically any cells... it will once again trigger an email. I do not want that to happen.

Comment: @Arm I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? I couldn't understand about ``but it is not necessarily required to know the value of 'G'.``. So I updated my script by the vision I understood. I'm really sorry for this situation. If this workaround was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you SO much! This works perfectly. I can't tell you how much I appreciate the time and effort you put into this... also, you did a fantastic job documenting the work!